# Why This TC Script Not Working

Tags: linux, bandwidth, qos, bandwidth-control, tc

Our application has three classes of traffic, and every type of traffic involves three ports. We want to limit the traffic by port number via TC, so I made a simple TC script to have the test, however the script doesnt work as I expected.

Below are those shell commands I use to set the TC. The expected result is that Downloading rate of SecureCRT and Apache (SecureCRT uses 22 port and Apache uses 80) will be limited to 100K/S, but the actual result we got is that Downloading rate remains unchanged -- about 5MB/s.

```
   tc qdisc del dev eth0 root
   tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1:0 cbq bandwidth 1Mbit avpkt 1000 cell 8

   tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:0 classid 1:1 cbq bandwidth 1Mbit rate 1Mbit 
   weight 100kbit prio 5 allot 1514 cell 8 maxburst 20 avpkt 1000 bounded

   tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:0 classid 1:2 cbq bandwidth 1Mbit rate 1Mbit
   weight 100kbit prio 5 allot 1514 cell 8 maxburst 20 avpkt 1000 bounded

   tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:0 classid 1:3 cbq bandwidth 1Mbit rate 1Mbit
   weight 100kbit prio 5 allot 1514 cell 8 maxburst 20 avpkt 1000 bounded


   tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:1 classid 1:1001 cbq bandwidth 1Mbit rate 
   800kbit weight 80kbit prio 8 allot 1514 cell 8 maxburst 20 avpkt 1000
   tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:1001 handle 1001: sfq

   tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:1 classid 1:1002 cbq bandwidth 1Mbit rate
   800kbit weight 80kbit prio 8 allot 1514 cell 8 maxburst 20 avpkt 1000
   tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:1002 handle 1002: sfq

   tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:1 classid 1:1003 cbq bandwidth 1Mbit rate 
   800kbit weight 80kbit prio 8 allot 1514 cell 8 maxburst 20 avpkt 1000
   tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:1003 handle 1003: sfq


   tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:2 classid 1:2001 cbq bandwidth 1Mbit rate
    800kbit weight 80kbit prio 8 allot 1514 cell 8 maxburst 20 avpkt 1000
   tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:2001 handle 2001: sfq

   tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:2 classid 1:2002 cbq bandwidth 1Mbit rate
      800kbit weight 80kbit prio 8 allot 1514 cell 8 maxburst 20 avpkt 1000
   tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:2002 handle 2002: sfq

   tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:2 classid 1:2003 cbq bandwidth 1Mbit rate 
      800kbit weight 80kbit prio 8 allot 1514 cell 8 maxburst 20 avpkt 1000
   tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:2003 handle 2003: sfq


   tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:3 classid 1:3001 cbq bandwidth 1Mbit rate
      800kbit weight 80kbit prio 8 allot 1514 cell 8 maxburst 20 avpkt 1000
   tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:3001 handle 3001: sfq

   tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:3 classid 1:3002 cbq bandwidth 1Mbit rate
     800kbit weight 80kbit prio 8 allot 1514 cell 8 maxburst 20 avpkt 1000
   tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:3002 handle 3002: sfq

   tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:3 classid 1:3003 cbq bandwidth 1Mbit rate
     800kbit weight 80kbit prio 8 allot 1514 cell 8 maxburst 20 avpkt 1000
   tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:3003 handle 3003: sfq

   tc filter add dev eth0 parent 1:0 protocol ip prio 1 u32 match ip sport 
             80 0xffff flowid 1:3001
   tc filter add dev eth0 parent 1:0 protocol ip prio 1 u32 match ip sport
             22 0xffff flowid 1:3002
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't classify traffic and then use shaping or delaying on ["incoming" traffic or on `ingress`](https://serverfault.com/q/537983/182140) how it's often called. This diagram is borrowed from [LARTC document](http://www.lartc.org/lartc.html):

```
 Userspace programs
                     ^
                     |
     +---------------+-----------------------------------------+
     |               Y                                         |
     |    -------> IP Stack                                    |
     |   |              |                                      |
     |   |              Y                                      |
     |   |              Y                                      |
     |   ^              |                                      |
     |   |  / ----------> Forwarding ->                        |
     |   ^ /                           |                       |
     |   |/                            Y                       |
     |   |                             |                       |
     |   ^                             Y          /-qdisc1-\   |
     |   |                            Egress     /--qdisc2--\  |
  --->->Ingress                       Classifier ---qdisc3---- | ->
     |   Qdisc                                   \__qdisc4__/  |
     |                                            \-qdiscN_/   |
     |                                                         |
     +----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Linux has simple ingres qdisc but it's features are very limited as there is no ingress queue. But it is possible to workaround it with `IMQ device` (InterMediate Queuing device) which "emulates" queuing on ingress.

Moreover, you can shape/delay incoming traffic when your server acts as a router (with IP forwarding turned on). If the server has two network interfaces - e.g. eth0 for Internet access and eth1 for local network access - and a client from the local network is downloading something, then, this traffic is incoming/ingress on eth0 interface and outgoing/egress on eth1 interface. So if you define your QoS policy on eth1 interface it will work.

Finally, I would recommend you to switch to `htb` qdisc from `cbq` as it is more accurate (it uses `TBF` or Token Bucket Filter  which does not depend on interface characteristics).